# Getting Websocket Error But Not Using Websockets in Code

Tags: javascript, websocket

I keep getting this websocket error when I run npm run dev. I'm working in a group of WSL and Mac users and our repo all works for them but I'm the only that gets this issue when trying to run our application. At a loss for why this is happening.

[Websocket Error when running npm run dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu7ZZ.png)

This is our webpack configuration file.

```
var path = require("path");
var HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
        publicPath: '/build',
        filename: "index_bundle.js"
    },
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.tsx?/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
          },
          {
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
                plugins: ["@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx"]
              },
            },
            exclude: /npm_modules/
          },
          {
            //npm install -D sass-loader css-loader style-loader webpack
            // /\.s[ac]ss$/i
            // /\.css /
            test: /\.s?css/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"
            ],
          },
          {
            // Now we apply rule for images
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
            use: [
              {
                // Using file-loader for these files
                loader: "file-loader",
                // loader: "url-loader",
                // In options we can set different things like format
                // and directory to save
                options: {
                  outputPath: '/images'
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          // {
          //   test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
          //   loader: 'url-loader'
          // },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        // Enable importing JS / JSX files without specifying their extension
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".ts"],
    },
    devServer: {
      static: {
        directory: path.join(__dirname, '/src'),
        },
      proxy: {
        '/': 'http://localhost:3000'
      },
      compress: true,
      port: 8080,
  },
};
```

Comment: if it works for everybody else then you, its probably not the code but your environment. Ask what node version others are using, perhaps you need to upgrade your node and npm to newer versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer / a working solution. I changed the port from 8080 in our devServer to 9000 and it worked, I'm not sure why that worked but it did. I also found this a recommended solution in the snowpack.dev docs that say to do the same thing.
https://www.snowpack.dev/reference/common-error-details